# PrimeFaces client side validation with p:autocomplete

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces 6 with JSF 2.2 (Mojarra). I want use the PrimeFaces's client side validation (CSV), but with `p:autocomplete` it doesn't work.

```
<p:autoComplete multiple="true" value="#{portfolio.tags}" minQueryLength="3" 
                forceSelection="true" id="tags" maxResults="5"
                required="true"
                requiredMessage="#{msg['portfolio.tags.number']}"
                completeMethod="#{sessionController.tagAutoComplete}">
    <f:validator validatorId="tagValidator"/>
</p:autoComplete>
```

Below the validator:

```
PrimeFaces.validator['tagValidator'] = {
            validate : function(element, value) {
                alert("ok");
        if (value == null || value.length < 5) {
            throw {
                summary : 'Validation Error',
                detail : 'Validation error'
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I noticed that it never invokes `tagValidator` java class instance instead of `PrimeFaces.validator['tagValidator']` javascript implementation. The CSV works correctly with `p:inputText`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the 'tagsValidator' client-side validation? Or better yet, create an [mcve]

Comment: Yes, I have tagValidator (Javascript validator) but the validation doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your validator on [GitHub PF showcase](https://github.com/primefaces/showcase) and it works for both (input and autocomplete) components. In both cases JS validation fired at the begining and after that Java validator was invoked.

You did not provide whole code but important parts are:

1. First you have to switch on CSV mechanism by setting context-param `<context-param>
   <param-name>primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>` but you probably did this if validation work for input.
2. You have to provide `validateClient="true"` attribute on your commandButton/commandLink
3. Your validator class in Java has to provide properly validatorId. You can find it in [PF showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/csv/custom.xhtml) (take a look at EmailValidator class) `public String getValidatorId() {
       return "custom.emailValidator";
   }`. 
   You can check if `f:validator validatorId` is generated properly in html code in browser (use for example Firebug -> there should be generated in `data-p-val="custom.emailValidator"`.

Check this 3 points. If it will not work please provide your Java validator.